# Promises in angularjs don't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an factory that gets data from my backend:

```
as.factory("abbdata", function GetAbbData($http,$rootScope,$routeParams,$q) {   //$q = promise
            var deffered = $q.defer();
            var data = [];
            var abbdata = {};

            abbdata.async = function () {
                $http.get($rootScope.appUrl + '/nao/summary/' + $routeParams['id']).success(function(d) {
                data = d.abbData;
                deffered.resolve();
            });

            return deffered.promise;
        };

        abbdata.data = function() {
            return data;
        };

        return abbdata;
        });
```

A call my factory like this in my controller:

```
abbdata.async().then(function() {
        $scope.abbData = abbdata.data(); //Contains data
    });
```

When I do a `console.log($scope.abbData)` outside my service call, just underneath, the result Is undifined. Why? Should not the `$scope.abbData` contain the data from my service after I call it?

EDIT:

[image: firebug]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you `console.log($scope.abbData)` outside the service call it should show `undefined`, since the call is asynchronous.

```
abbdata.async().then(function() {
    $scope.abbData = abbdata.data(); //Contains data
});
console.log($scope.abbData) // this should show undefined
```

The `console.log($scope.abbData)` just after setting the abbData should show the data

```
abbdata.async().then(function() {
    $scope.abbData = abbdata.data(); //Contains data
    console.log($scope.abbData) // this should show the data
});
```

**EDIT**

you can use abbData from your service call like for example

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope, abbdata){
    var updateUI;    
    $scope.abbData = [];

    abbdata.async().then(function() {
        $scope.abbData = abbdata.data(); //Contains data
        updateUI();
    });
    updateUI = function(){
        //do something with $scope.abbData
    }
});
```

**EDIT 2**

On response to your query, I would do something like,

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('JobsCtrl', function($scope, $jobService) {
    $scope.jobs = [];
    $jobService.all().then(function(jobs) {
        $scope.jobs = jobs;
    });
})
.service('$jobService', function ($q, $http) {
    return {
        all: function () {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http({
                url: 'http://url',
                method: "GET"
            }).success(function (data) {
                deferred.resolve(data);
            }).error(function () {
                deferred.reject("connection issue");
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }    
});
```

associated view

```
<body ng-app = "myApp">
    <div ng-controller = "JobsCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="job in jobs track by job.id">
            <a href="#/tab/jobs/{{job.id}}" class="item item-icon-right">
                <h2>{{job.job_name}}</h2>
                <p>DUE DATE: {{job.job_due_date}}</p>
            </a>
        </div>
    <div>
</body>
```

1. Here the service an all function which returns a promise, i.e. it will notify when data is fetched.
2. in the controller the service is called and as soon the service call is resolved the $scope.jobs is assigned by the resolved data.
3. the $scope.jobs is used in the angular view. as soon as the jobs data are resolved, i.e. $scope.jobs is assigned, the view is updated.

hope this helps

Comment: How can I make the data from my service call accesible outside my service call then?

Comment: You have to design your app in a promise based fashion. On the other hand if you use angular directives like `ng-repeat` it will automatically update your UI as `$scope` object watches for changes in data

Comment: Is it any other way to make my data from my service accessible outside the call to my service? How should you do it?

Comment: @shaikb: Must I alway put my code that are going to use $scope.abbData, inside my service call?

Comment: Not necessarily, see my first edit. you can compose a function ex. `updateUI` where you use the `$scope.abbData` and call the function after service returns the data. But yes functionalities depending on `$scope.abbData` must be initiated after service returns data, i.e. resolving

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the data that should be returned into the resolve function like this:

```
deffered.resolve(data);
```

EDIT:
To get the data in the controller do this:

```
abbdata.async().then(function(data) {
        $scope.abbData = data; //Contains data
    });
```

Comment: It's still undefined.

Comment: Could you check with a debugger if the success function is called in your service factory? And if 'd' is defined there?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply return that value from the async call in the first place?

You can chain promises so by attaching a success handler in your factory and returning a value from that you can simplify your code to:

```
as.factory("abbdata", function GetAbbData($http,$rootScope,$routeParams) {
    return {
        async: function () {
            return $http.get($rootScope.appUrl + '/nao/summary/' + $routeParams['id']).success(function(d) {
                return d.data.abbData;
            });
        }
     }
});
```

And then use it like

```
abbdata.async().then(function(data) {
    $scope.abbData = data; //Contains data
});
```

Comment: Hm, I don't know actually. But why does not my code work? What am I doing wrong? I want to udnerstand :)

Comment: Markus explained that, it because you did not pass the data to the resolve call. I've added this into my answer

Comment: I have tried Markus code samples, and I still get an Error $scope.abbData is undifined. And I get the same error with your code sample

Comment: Are you sure the call returns data? :) log the result variable `d` and see what that gives

Comment: Yes, If I write console.log($scope.abbData) inside my service call, the output is an object containing data.

Comment: You'll need to look for it under the `data` property `d.data.abbData`, I updated this in my answer.

Comment: Your update code does not work. Now I also get the error: TypeError: d.data is undefined

Comment: I'm currently at work and chat is apparantly blocked by the proxy (great). The image you showed me, is this the console.log output of `d` ? Because that contains a data key AFAICT

Comment: Anzeo: In your suggestion, wouldn't you need to use the .success() callback in the controller instead of .then(), since you are returning that from the service call?

Comment: @Anzeo: The image Is the output from my $scope.abbData inside my service call

Comment: @Markus, no, it still returns a promise. Success is just a shorthand for `then(function(){})` and `catch` is a shorthand for `then(undefined, function(){})`.

Comment: @user500468 Please log the variable `d` in the success callback

Comment: @Anzeo: The output when I log d, Is an object from my backend, which Is correct.

Comment: Yes, but I don't think that it contains the key you're looking for. Post the output in your question as an edit so I can verify

Comment: @Anzeo: My backend return 3 objects, and the object That I want to use, Is called abbData. So I should return d.abbData? Check my updated question.

Comment: You posted the same screenshot, I need to know what the variable `d` is in your success handler, don't log out the $scope.variable. I can't tell what the method is returning now so I also can't show you how you should get the data correctly

Comment: @Anzeo: That was the output from my d variable in my sevice. Not the scope variable In my controller. How can I mkae the data from my service, accessible outside my service call in my controller?

Answer (score 0):

I had a quick look, I have 2 ideas:

- First theory: your service is returning undefined.
- Second theory: you need to run $scope.$apply();

See this fiddler: https://jsfiddle.net/Lgfxtfm2/1/

```
'use strict';
var GetAbbData = function($q) {   
//$q = promise
var deffered = $q.defer();
var data = [];
var abbdata = {};

abbdata.async = function () {
    setTimeout(function() {
        //1: set dummy data
        //data = [200, 201];
        //2: do nothing
        //
        //3: set data as undefined
        //data = undefined;
        deffered.resolve();
    }, 100);

    return deffered.promise;
};

abbdata.data = function() {
    return data;
};

return abbdata;
};
var abbdata = GetAbbData(Q)
abbdata.async().then(function() {
    console.log(abbdata.data()); //Contains data
});
```

I have stripped away a lot of dependencies and replaced $q with Q just for my own ease.

In the above example, I first attempted to run the code with dummy data, the console output the expected data, then I tried to not assign the data, and I get an empty array. This is why I assume that if you are seeing 'undefined' you must be explicitly setting the value to 'undefined'.

That aside, I also noticed that you were testing the result by reading directly from $scope. I know that when not inside the angular scope, doing operations on the $scope object does not necessarily happen in a timely manner, and typing $scope.$apply() usually fixes this. Usually, when using $http, angular keeps you in the appropriate scope, but you are creating your own promise using $q so this could be another potential issue.

Finally, the other two answers have pointed out that you are not using promises in the standard way. Although your code works fine, it is not normal to set your data directly onto your service and retrieve it from there. You can keep your service stateless by simply resolving your promise with the data that you want to process in the then method as shown by the answers by Anzeo and Markus.

I hope I was able to find the solution, good luck.

Dipun

Answer (score 0):

```
as.factory("abbdata", function GetAbbData($http,$rootScope,$routeParams,$q) {   //$q = promise
            var deffered = $q.defer();
            var data = [];
            var abbdata = {};

            abbdata.async = function () {
                $http.get($rootScope.appUrl + '/nao/summary/' + $routeParams['id']).success(function(d) {
                data = d.abbData;
                deffered.resolve(data);
            });

            return deffered.promise;
        };

        abbdata.data = function() {
            return data;
        };

        return abbdata;
        });
```